# PHP Foreach in SmartyBC. Smarty template

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I'm relatively new to Smarty and can't seem to figure this out.

In my php controller I instanciate a class "Product" as many times as I will need to display it. For instance if I have 5 different items on my page I will instanciate "Product" 5 times. I then create an array containing these. It goes something like this :
(my objects are filled with infos on the product).

Code:

`$product_array = array (
0 => Object1,
1 => Object2); etc.`

I then assign that array to a smarty variable {$product_array}.
Once in my .tpl I go through a loop of the displayed products. That's when I would need to assign $products_array[0] or {$products_array.0} to another variable $products that would display everything I need about the product. Then it will go through the loop again and show me {$products_array.1} and so on.

However this seems impossible seeing that any way I try and achieve this (and I even tried using {php} shame on me) I can't seem to figure it out.
I get this error : Object of class Product could not be converted to string.

Comment: you can't do that and it won't work. You need to change the logic. Either use pure PHP or pure smarty. Don't combine both.

Comment: Do your businses logic in the controller, and don't instantiate models in the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im pretty sure you cant mix in smarty stuff within a `{php}` tag. But the questions is why do this? Why not create all the products and put them in an array, and then assign that to smarty and loop over it in smarty syntax?

```
{php}
    $accesories = $GLOBALS['accessories'];
    $products = array();
    foreach($accesories as $k => $v)
    {
        var_dump($instantProduct = new Product($accesories[$k], TRUE));
        $products[$k] = new Product($accesories[$k], TRUE);
    }

    $smarty->assign('products', $products);
{/php}

// now loop and conditions in smarty
```

That said you really should just fix this now and move this logic into whatever youre using as a "controller". It may reveal more widespread problems with your design that you are going to have to solve one way or another.